# Different permissions for each group for one folder

Tags: command-line, permissions, samba

I am running Ubuntu and I have a question about **groups** and **permissions**

I have three groups which are: group_one, group_two, group_three

I have three folders which are share1 share2 share3

I want to give:

```
group_one read write to share1 <br/>
group_two read to share 1 <br/>
group_three read to share 1
```

```
group_one read to share2 <br/>
group_two read to share2 <br/>
group_three read and write to share3
```

```
group_one read write to share3 <br/>
group_two read to share 3 <br/>
group_three read to share3
```

From what I can find online only one group can own a folder and **chmod** can only change the folder permissions once for the group I am in.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is this some kind of homework? the file permission controls are user, group, others - so my way would be give read/write to group and read to others, than make the corresponding group the owner

Comment: Thanks, I changed the group ownership using chgrp, then i used chmod to remove -rwx permissions and assigned permissions, then again for others with the seperate permissions. Thanks

Comment: write up a nice answer - explaining the commands etc. so others have the chance to use that too